# Transfer at Munich

Tags: munich, dusseldorf

We are travelling to Dusseldorf next April have booked tickets from Singapore Flight LH791 to Dusseldorf which takes us through Munich. The flight has just been updated - arriving now Munich at 05:50am and the flight to Dusseldorf is LH2002 at 06:30am to Dusseldorf? Do we have time to transfer the agent suggest okay?

Comment: 40 minutes to disembark, collect luggage, clear customs and immigration and get to your connecting flight is extremely tight. I'd say it's not doable. You should look to change your connecting flight.

Comment: thank you thought would be the case - agent suggested as it is a "through ticket" Luthhansa would sort it...

Comment: If you don't make your connection Lufthansa will place you on the next available flight. If you're travelling on a busy day and the next flight is already full you'll be bumped to the next one and so on. You could be stuck for hours. Better to fix it now, which should be easy to do since it's Lufthansa's change that has necessitated it.

Comment: @CannonFodder: Why would he need to collect luggage? Undoubtedly that will be checked through.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Munich will be his point of entry to the Schengen area. Hell clear customs there.

Comment: @CannonFodder He'll need to go through immigration at Munich, since it's his point of entry to the Schengen area, but his bags should be checked through to Dusseldorf with no need (or ability) to claim them in Munich.

Comment: @CannonFodder, most cases you clear immigration on your first entry to the Schengen area, but customs at your final destination. I am just not sure in this case as Munich/Frankfurt is fully in one country.

Comment: When transfering, you never care about luggage as that's automatically re-added to the next flight, and for customs, you only need at the last airport (as you go out to the country), international airport areas do not represent the country area and you are free to move around, as long as you don't leave the airport. Just get out of the airplane and see the board for your next flight... eat/drink something and on your way to gate. You can always call the airport and ask for all of this info, I do plenty of transfers :)

Comment: In case anyone is still in doubt of where to clear customs, [this page](https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/business/customs-controls/travelling-air_en) gives details about the procedures when flying within/to the EU. No. 5 is the example relevant to this question (I never experienced a check of hand luggage at the first airport).

Comment: @balexandre: "Never" is a much too strong word to use here. It happens to be right that the OP will not see his luggage is Munich, but for example with an international-to-domestic transfer (or even, I think, international-to-international) at an airport in USA you definitely need to care about luggage. And "as long as you don't leave the airport" is generally false whenever there's a domestic flight involved (though with the OP's short connection he doesn't have time to even contemplate exiting the airport).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It sounds tight-ish but doable. Munich airport is usually spoken of as extremely efficient for connections -- the minimum connection time for Lufthansa international-domestic is just **30 minutes**. They consider this swift connection a definite selling point, and they go to quite some effort to keep it, including such things as proactively fast-tracking late arriving passengers past the lines. Though you're of course always sensitive to immigration delays.

The good news then is that Lufthansa will be responsible for rebooking you if you miss the connection. And Lufthansa fly **a lot** of direct flights from Munich to Düsseldorf. On the random Wednesday in January I searched for, there are flights departing at:

> 06:30, 07:30, 08:00, 08:30, 08:45, 09:30, 10:30, 11:30, 13:10, 13:30, 15:30, 16:30, 17:30, 17:45, 18:00, 18:30, 19:00, 19:30, 20:45, 21:30

No matter how long you're held up for at immigration, there will be a flight leaving for Düsseldorf quite soon afterwards that they can put you on.

Comment: Also quite possible, given this is just a connection there will be a Lufthansa staff member right outside the plane to take you to your new gate.